# Receive the data in Python, BS4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to parse some data from website: busstop_name, indicator. Here is my code, it returns empty div. But Chrome shows the data I need. How can I get the data: time of the bus(indicator) and stop(busstop_name)?

```
def extract_bus_info(url):
    html = get_html(url)    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    a1 = soup.find_all("div", "htmlr a1")
    for a in a1:
        print(a)
```

What I recieve.

```
<div class="htmlr a1"></div>
```

Link:https://www.bustime.ru/angarsk/#bus-28

Comment: I checked this on the website and it is just an empty div. Your code is working fine. To find the elements with the information you need, check them within your browser. In chrome or firefox: right click on the element, select the "inspect" option from the dropdown menu and then read the id or class attribute that you will use to find the element with beautifulsoup.

Comment: That div contains other divs. It's not an empty one. I've tried what you said - it still keep on sending me empty div or none. Also I've tried to find only one div by id: ```a1 = soup.find(id="243571") ```. I receive None. I guess it happens because of AJAX request or something else, but can't figure out what excaty.

Comment: The div specified by `class="htmlr a1"` is empty. `Ctrl-F` on "view-source:https://www.bustime.ru/angarsk/#bus-28" for `class="htmlr a1"` - it is immediatly closed by `</div>`. The bus name for example can be found in `class="bustable_head__bus"`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. The main feature of bs4 and requests is that those libs are static. That means that they bring up the website you need and then take the pure html. If the site has information that uploads with JS, it will not be shown in the html. You need to use selenuim to recieve the dynamic data.